# Is there any opensource DB2 client?

Tags: db2

I am using db2 version 7 , i need an windows application (similar to MSSQL) to do the database operations.

Comment: Does it have to be open source? Isn't there an official DB2 client for Windows? And also things like JDBC drivers?

Comment: is that official db2 client free to use?

Comment: In my view Plotly Falcon is a great open source SQL editor for Db2: https://plot.ly/free-sql-client-download/

Answer (score 16):

You can use [Oracle's SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html), its quite good and its FREE.

But you will need to download and import [db2jcc.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/d/Downloaddb2jccjar.htm) in the under tools>preferences>database>third party JDBC drivers option.

Hope this helped :)

Comment: The db2jcc.jar link doesn't work anymore. It says Not Found when trying to download it.

Comment: DB2 JDBC Driver Versions and Downloads: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866

Answer (score 11):

Came across this thread as I was doing research on this question. Figured I'd add my two cents in case someone else swings through via the Googles

I've found two Open-Source clients:

- Squirrel: http://www.squirrelsql.org/
- Eclipse:  http://eclipsesql.sourceforge.net/index.php

I've not used either, but they both look fairly solid. The recommendations I've gotten have steered me towards Squirrel, but it seems to be more personal preference than anything.

Comment: So, over the time I've used it - the free version of Eclipse is almost unusable. I'm sure it's great if you can pay for it, but I'm definitely happier with Squirrel.

Answer (score 6):

Personally I recommend [DBVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/) (Java client) or [IBM Data Studio](https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/ibm-data-studio) (eclipse based). Both are free ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly certain even if you have an open-source client, you still have to download the DB2 driver which only comes through IBM.

The official clients are free to download and use.

You may want to consult [this page](http://www.db2dean.com/Previous/DB2Client.html) to determine which of the download options you want.